# Match controller name and call specific function

Tags: php

I've created a class called `Router` that import all the controller like this:

```
<?php

 include dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '\application\controllers\backend.php';

 class Router
 {
    private $_backend;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->_backend = new Backend();
    }

    /**
    * Execute function
    */

    public function submit($controller, $func)
    {
      // $this->_backend->index(); 
     } 
 }

?>
```

now this class is available in my `router.php` file, this file is included before anyone else, and I can access to the router class in any php files by reference:

```
$router = new Router();
```

my task is call a function `index` available in `backend` controller imported in `router.php` file. In `index.php` file I have:

```
$router->submit('backend', 'index');
```

How I can match the controller name and call the function passed as parameter with the variable inside my `Router` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 class Router
 {
    public function submit($controller, $func)
    {
      // include dynamically the needed file
      include dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '\application\controllers\' . $controller . '.php';
      // The classname starts with capital
      $Class = ucfirst($controller);
      // create an instance
      $ctr = new $Class();
      // and call the requested function
      $ctr->$func();
     } 
 }
```

Comment: So I can't import all the controllers at the top of the Router class and call a specific controller depending on the parameter passed?

Comment: you can, include all of them at the top, and remove the include line from my code